# Can I assign a specific port to a windows service?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I am going to deploy a windows service in a windows server. Can I assign a specific port to it? Say port `55442`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is something that would be taken care of by your service. You would define what port it will use in the source code. If you wanted the port to be configurable, you'd use a config file or a registry setting. If you didn't write the Windows service, then consult the vendor's documentation.

Comment: Hi Ryan, I'm running into a similar situation as the OP. I'm trying to set the `service` argument of `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule`, and I see that working, but my client can't connect. `netstat` shows that the executable, `java.exe` owns the port rather than the service. Is there any way to do what OP was asking and tie the port to the service?